# What does (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__array_interface__') mean?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, model, nonetype

I am trying to make a machine learning program which classifies an image of a cell as an infected or uninfected. I created the model on a separate python file and am creating a script which will call it on an image to classify it. Here is the full code:

```
def convert(img):
    img1 = cv2.imread(img)
    img = Image.fromarray(img1, 'RGB')
    image = img.resize((50, 50))
    return (np.array(image))
def cell_name(label):
    if label == 0:
        return ("Paracitized")
    if label == 1:
        return ("Uninfected")
def predict(file):
    print ("Predicting...please wait")
    ar = convert(file)
    ar = ar/255
    label = 1
    a = []
    ar.append(ar)
    a = np.array(a)
    score = loaded_model.predict(a, verbose=1)
    print (score)
    label_index=np.argmax(score)
    print(label_index)
    acc=np.max(score)
    Cell=cell_name(label_index)
    return (Cell,"The predicted Cell is a "+Cell+" with accuracy =    "+str(acc))

print(predict("test/paracitized.png"))
```

Here is the full error message:

```
File "malaria_img.py", line 15, in convert
    img = Image.fromarray(img1, 'RGB')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2526, in fromarray
    arr = obj.__array_interface__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'
```

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Comment: As an aside, Python 2.7 is **very much** out of date, and will **not be supported** as of the end of this year. You should update to 3.x as soon as possible.

Comment: I tried convert function in my system it is executing fine. There may be problem with your filename as stated by @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arr = obj.__array_interface__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'
```

`AttributeError` means that there was an `Error` that had to do with an `Attribute` request. In general, when you write `x.y`, `y` is the purported `attribute` of x.

`'NoneType' object` means an object which has `NoneType` as its type. There is exactly one such object, called `None` (you should be familiar with it). It, indeed, `has no attribute` that is named `__array_interface__`.

The problem is that we are asking for this attribute from `obj`, but `obj` has the value `None`. It was supposed to be some kind of array-like object instead. This is not in our own code; rather, `obj` is PIL's internal name for the `img1` that we passed in to the `fromarray` call.

The `img1` in our own code comes from the previous line, `img1 = cv2.imread(img)`. The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread) tells us (sort of - because it's trying to document the C++ and Python versions simultaneously; you kinda have to fill in some blanks here) that CV2 returns `None` when `the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format)`.

Double-check your filename (if the filename came from processing a string, check for unexpected whitespace, and double-check the extension on the filename); double-check the file *path* (if you gave a relative path, double-check what the working directory is - you maybe surprised!); and double-check the file itself (does the Python process have permissions to open it? Is the image corrupted?).

Comment: While the solution is simple this time, I hope I gave you some ideas about debugging in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your convert function. You try to turn the image to array and then inside your code you are trying to turn it again to array. Remove one of them and test your code again. I revised your function:

```
def convert(img):
   img1 = cv2.imread(img)
   img = Image.fromarray(img1, 'RGB')
   image = img.resize((50, 50))
   return image
```